# What does っか mean after the imperative form?

Tags: grammar, particle-か

I was watching Chainsaw Man and found these sentences.

> 動け**っか**?

Or the second sentence below:

Person 1:

> 殺すのはもったいない顔だけど、死んでちょうだい

Person 2:

> 胸を揉む前に死ね**っかよ**

Comment: These may answer your question: [What is the よっか in はじめよっか?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11639/45489) /  [Meaning of したくすっか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94183/45489) / [What does "ってっか" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66341/45489)

Comment: [This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11508/how-does-the-addition-of-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B-to-the-end-of-a-sentence-affect-the-meaning) also states 負けっかよ means "As if I would lose!" (in an exasperated or sarcastic tone), which does fit the context of the second example here as well -- "As if I would die before I cop a feel!"

Answer (score 2):

"動けるか？" is formal but in spooken language it sometimes change to "動けっか". In this case る became very short so "動けっか". I never speak like this but Son-Goku in Dragon Ball speaks like this. And "死ねるかよ" is also formal too.